# A design pattern for constructors

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor

I have been challenged by a design issue which I will try to describe below.

Suppose that a class, call it A, has a constructor with a bunch of parameters. Since it is tiring and dirty to write all those parameters in each instantiation, I have written another class, call it StyleSheetA, which encapsulates all those parameters and is the only parameter to the constructor of A. In this way, I can prepare some default StyleSheetA templates to be used later, and if it is needed, I can modify them.

And at this point, I need to extend A. Suppose B extends A. B will have its own stylesheet, namely StyleSheetB. I think it will be appropriate that StyleSheetB extends StyleSheetA, so with one stylesheet parameter, constructor of B can also construct its super class A. But I am afraid of the possibility that this design may have flaws. For example what if I decide to add a getter/setter for the stylesheet? Is there a novel way to handle all these situations? Am I in the wrong way? For those who are confused, I attach some code here:

```
    class A
    {
        StyleSheetA ss;

        A(StyleSheetA ss)
        {
            this.ss = ss;
            // Do some stuff with ingredients of styleSheet
        }
    }
    class StyleSheetA
    {
        int n1;
        int n2;
        // :
        // :
        int n100;
    }

    class B extends A
    {
        B(StyleSheetB ss)
        {
            super(ss);
            // Do some stuff with ingredients of styleSheet
        }
    }
    class StyleSheetB extends StyleSheetA
    {
        int n101;
        int n102;
        // :
        // :
        int n200;
    }
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions, also any of your critics will be appreciated.

Edit: I am developing in java me so there is no generics support.

Comment: It's not apparent (to me anyway) what language you're developing in, but usually generics/templates can help solve this problem. By making class A into A<T> you can specify the type of the composite (e.g. StyleSheetB) when deriving from it: class B extends A<StyleSheetB>. If you don't have such a feature, try C# ;)

Comment: Yeah, your solution would be really a good approach, but unfortunately I was developing in java me and there is no generic support in it. Thanks.

Comment: You should add a java-me tag. ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I was not expecting a generics solution, sorry.

Comment: This is StackOverflow. Expect the best ;)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that you are only moving the problem of having too many parameters from class `A` to class `StyleSheetA`.

To illustrate my point, think of this question: How would you instantiate `StyleSheetA`? Probably using a constructor that accepts all these parameters, anyway. The only benefit this design may give you is if you have a same set of parameter values encapsulated by an object of `StyleSheetA` which you will reuse among multiple instances of `A`. If so, bear in mind that although you'd have different instances of `A` they would share the same parameters, so it isn't a good choice.

What I could recommend you is to try to refactor your class `A` itself. Try to break it up into smaller classes. If nesseccary, try to create subclasses to avoid conditional branches, etc.

Now, I don't know how your class `A` looks like, but maybe if you do so you'll have several classes, each with its own set of parameters. And if any of the parameters is a discriminator (meaning that it determines the class "type") you will be able to get rid of it, just by using subclasses, and relying on built in type system to do it instead.

Comment: Using a composite class to encapsulate a bunch of related parameters is good practice, and also improves performance (ever so slightly).

Comment: @Morton: If they are indeed related, then I agree with you. I just disagree with writing artificial container classes just for the sake of having only one input parameter instead of many.

Comment: @Morten: You'd have to provide some explanation or proof of a performance improvement. @Goran is correct in saying that all this does is moving the problem from A to StyleSheetA: The number of parameters and variable assignments will remain exactly the same, plus you get an additional task: to instantiate a StyleSheetA object.  That is, unless you reuse the same StyleSheetA object for more than one instantiation of A - and get a whole bunch of possible side effects.  Also, it creates one more dependency to worry about.  I don't think that's good practice at all.

Comment: Having read the comments that were added while I was writing: Encapsulating **related** fields can make sense, if only to clean up the code.  I give you that ;)

Comment: Invoking a method is not a constant-time operation. Parameters a pushed onto the stack for the call and released when it completes, therefore a method with fewer parameters will perform better. Of course, to benefit you need to invoke it quite a few times. Additionally, when using many parameters there will not be registers available for all of them, which adds memory moves and lookups to what the processor needs to do. It's not something to worry about in everyday coding though :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using an IoC container, like StructureMap, to manage your constructor dependencies?  That might make a lot of this stuff easier.

Comment: Does the down-voter have something constructive to add?  One of the main reasons people use IoC containers is to help simplify constructor dependencies.

Comment: You can get a vote from me instead, I'm a big fan of IoC even if it may not solve this particular guys problem ;)

Comment: I agree with @Adam: It is not nice to down-vote and not give an explanation.  It also doesn't help anyone to understand why the answer wasn't helpful.

Comment: It still just moves the problem from the class to the IoC container (wasn't me :)) *However*, this approach may be quite useful if most of the time you'd use some default values for most of the parameters and special values only for some of them. Then, you could inject *all* the defaults from the container and additionally set the few different ones through setters.

Comment: It does move the problem to the IoC, but that code is usually contained in some bootstrapping config code at your programs entry point.  One of the premises of the question was that he made these spreadsheet classes to wrap up all the parameters to A and B.  With an IoC you could configure what parameters go with which classes, and how they're created, and let your IoC do the dirty work.  Of course since he's using Java, he probably won't be using StructureMap, but I'm sure Java has lots of nice IoCs available :)

Answer (score 2):

A thoughts on the getter and setter issue:

The constructor in 'B' implies that the additional parameters (n101+) are necessary for the operation of the class.  If you were just extending the class with a full parameter list, you would have getters and setters for n101...n200 in `B` and n1...n100 in `A`. This suggests perhaps not having `StylesheetB` extend `StylesheetA`, but rather have the constructor to class B be  `B(StyleSheetA,StyleSheetB)`, this way you can have a setter in class `A` for it's parameters, have that inherited and also put one in `B` for `StylesheetB`.

Comment: That would also work, although it might soon get awkward if additional nesting is needed.